# Remove Block Directly From Database - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, blocks, database

I created a block and put in some invalid PHP code resulted in entire site not accessible at all.

I'm fairly new to Drupal and I'm not a back-end programmer either. Much appreciated if you can provide a clear step-by-step guide on how to delete that particular block directly from the Database (PhpMyAdmin).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Login into PHPMy Admin with admin credentials
- Search for the *block* table; in this table search for the block which you have created
- Change the value of status column form 1 to 0
- Delete all the content from the *cache_bootstrap* table

Comment: Thanks! I ended up following your guide since it's a step by step instruction. Downside is that if there's a lot of rows then would be nice to have a more efficient way of finding the block than going through it manually.

Comment: To find rows in a database, you use `SELECT`; just use the right criteria to match the blocks you are looking for. Unfortunately, _Drupal Answers_ doesn't aim to teach you how to use PHPMyAdmin, since it is off-topic.

Comment: This solution does not remove the block at all, it merely disables it. If you need to [remove the block, see the answer below](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/176933/17285).

Answer (score 10):

To delete a block programmatically using the Database API, try this:

```
$module = 'block';
$delta = 1;

// Get the block id (bid) required to delete the correct block from table 'block_custom'
$result = db_select('block', 'b')
         ->fields('b', array('bid'))
         ->condition('module', $module)
         ->condition('delta', $delta)
         ->execute();
$bid = $result->fetchField();

db_delete('block_custom')
  ->condition('bid', $bid)
  ->execute();

db_delete('block')
  ->condition('module', $module)
  ->condition('delta', $delta)
  ->execute();

db_delete('block_role')
  ->condition('module', $module)
  ->condition('delta', $delta)
  ->execute();
```

When creating custom blocks through the Drupal Block UI, the module name is `block` and the `delta` value is an integer. Be sure to use the correct delta value to delete the desired block.

Comment: Boom. Thanks, Tyler. I'd also add block_node_type to the list. : )

Comment: *Warning!* Using `$delta` to match against `bid` in table `block_custom` is very dangerous as you will delete another block. You should use the `bid` id from table `block` instead.

Comment: Updated the example to fix the problem.

Comment: @ErikTöyrä In my case it seems that using `$delta` to match against `bid` works just fine. Are you really sure it's problematic?

Comment: @MilošKroulík: It has been over three years since I posted this, but yes, as I recall it may cause the wrong block to be deleted. We had a large Drupal installation with many modules adding blocks.

Comment: Hi, according to documentation https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x the second parameter of fields() method should be an array otherwise you will get an error: ->fields('b', array('bid')).

Answer (score 3):

just use this simple query to delete the block.

```
delete from block where module = 'MODULE' and title = 'TITLE'
```

Replace *MODULE* with the name of the module creating the block, and *TITLE* with the block title.

If the block doesn't have a title, you could use only `delete from block where module = 'MODULE'`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :) What would be the query to search instead of delete? Can I replace `delete` with `search` or something like that?

Comment: yes the query would be `SELECT * FROM  block WHERE module = 'MODULE'` replace MODULE by the module creating the block i.e. `search`

Comment: What if I don't know my block name? How does a block name translate into the database? Is everything in lowercase with underscores instead of spaces?

Answer (score 0):

delete from block where delta = '[DELTA]';

If you created the block programmatically you should be able to recreate the delta value with the same logic you used to create it. It's the value you passed as the KEY to your blocks array for example $blocks['myblock'] -- myblock is the value stored in delta.

On an aside, I personally think its a good idea to prefix this name with your module prefix. When I look in my Blocks table, I can see mymodule_myblock for my delta and there is no ambiguity.